# Proof of probabilty notation

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> $G$ is the event of a customer buying a goldfish from a pet shop and $T$ is the event of a customer buying a tortoise at a pet shop.
>
> $\operatorname P(T)$ is twice $\operatorname P(G)$, $\operatorname P(G \ \text{nor}\ T)=0.42$ and $G$ and $T$ are independent.
>
> i) Show that  $2a+b=c$
>
> ii) Show that $a=\sqrt\frac b2-b$

I am not quite sure what I have to do here. I know the formula that can be used if they are independent but I do not think that works here.

Here is a picture of the venn diagram. I need to find out what $a$, $b$ and $c$ are.

[image]

Comment: where do a,b and c come from?

Comment: @Alex It looks like $a=P(T)$, $b=P(G)$ and $c=P(G\text{ nor }T)$.

Comment: i changed it now sorry

Answer (score 0):

> [image: Venn Diagram]

From the diagram: $a=\mathsf P(G\setminus T), \\b=\mathsf P(G\cap T), \\ c=\mathsf P(T\setminus G)$, thus $\mathsf P(G)=a+b, \\ \mathsf P(T)=b+c, \\ \mathsf P(\underbrace{(G\cap T)^\complement}_{G\textsf{ xnor }T})= 1-(a+b+c)$

So since you know that: $ \mathsf P(T) = 2\mathsf P(G)\;$ and $\;\mathsf P((G\cap T)^\complement)=0.42$

Can you continue?

Comment: No, I do not know what to do from there. Could you then arrive to 0.58=a+b+c?

Comment: @JoseCornielle Yes.  $(b+c)=2(a+b)$ and $\frac {29}{50}=a+b+c$ means...